# discord bot : application did not respond

Tags: python

changed some of the code to add realms bot loads up find and shows no errors but when using the command on discord it shows application did not respond. im not to sure whats stopping it from responding

```
import json
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import os
import traceback
import string
import datetime



class LFGCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_interaction(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

        if "custom_id" not in interaction.data:
            return

        userid = interaction.user.id
        if interaction.user.avatar is None:
            userpfp = interaction.user.default_avatar
        else:
            userpfp = interaction.user.avatar

        class ChoiceView(discord.ui.View):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(timeout=None)
                self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label=f"Join", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id=f"join", disabled=False))
                self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label=f"Leave", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id=f"leave", disabled=False))

        try:
            if interaction.data["custom_id"].startswith("createmodal"):
                diff = interaction.data['components'][0]['components'][0]['value']
                if diff.lower() not in ("soft", "softcore", "hard", "hardcore"):
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Invalid difficulty, choose between softcore/hardcore", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                realm = interaction.data['components'][0]['components'][0]['value']
                if realm.lower() not in ("eternal", "seasonal"):
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Invalid Realm name, choose between Eternal/Seasonal", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                dungeon = interaction.data['components'][1]['components'][0]['value']
                if dungeon != "":
                    if dungeon.lower() not in ("normal", "nightmare"):
                        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Invalid dungeon type, choose between normal/nightmare", ephemeral=True)
                        return
                else:
                    dungeon = None
                try:
                    level = int(interaction.data['components'][2]['components'][0]['value'])
                    party = int(interaction.data['components'][3]['components'][0]['value'])
                    if party < 1:
                        raise ValueError
                    if level < 0:
                        raise ValueError
                except ValueError:
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Invalid Sigil Level/party size, please supply a valid number.", ephemeral=True)
                    return

                desc = interaction.data['components'][4]['components'][0]['value']
                if desc == "":
                    desc = None
                

                class DropdownMenu(discord.ui.Select):
                    def __init__(self, options):
                        super().__init__(placeholder=f"Group Type", min_values=1, max_values=1,
                                        options=options, custom_id="grouptype")
                        
                class DropdownMenu2(discord.ui.Select):
                    def __init__(self, options):
                        super().__init__(placeholder=f"World Type", min_values=1, max_values=1,
                                        options=options, custom_id="worldtype")


                class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
                    def __init__(self, options1, options2):
                        super().__init__(timeout=None)
                        self.add_item(DropdownMenu(options1))
                        self.add_item(DropdownMenu2(options2))

                
                groups = ["Seasonal leveling", "Dungeon's", "Capstone Dungeon's", "Helltide's", "World Boss", "Renown Quest's", "PVP"]
                worlds = ["World Tier 1", "World Tier 2", "World Tier 3", "World Tier 4"]

                optionlist1 = []
                optionlist2 = []

                for group in groups:
                    optionlist1.append(discord.SelectOption(
                        emoji="",
                        label=group,
                        description=""
                    ))

                for world in worlds:
                    optionlist2.append(discord.SelectOption(
                        emoji="",
                        label=world,
                        description=""
                    ))

                emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Group Request", description=f"**Description:** {'None' if desc is None else desc}\n**realm:** {realm.lower().capitalize()}\n**Difficulty:** {diff.lower().capitalize()}\n**Dungeon:** {'None' if dungeon is None else dungeon.lower().capitalize()}\n**Sigil Level:** {level}\n**Party Size:** {party}", colour=discord.Colour.red())
                emb.set_author(name=interaction.user, icon_url=userpfp)
                emb.set_thumbnail(url=userpfp)
                emb.add_field(name="Options", value=f"**Group Type:** Not selected\n**World Type:** Not selected", inline=False)
                emb.set_footer(text="Fill in each option to post the LFG request.")
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, view=DropdownView(optionlist1, optionlist2))
                return


            elif interaction.data["custom_id"].startswith("grouptype"):
                if interaction.message.interaction.user != interaction.user:
                    await interaction.response.send_message("This LFG request is not yours.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                with open("config.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    config = json.load(f)
                    channelid = config["channel"]

                grouptype = interaction.data['values'][0]
                emb = interaction.message.embeds[0]
                descrip = emb.description

                desc = descrip.split("Description:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                diff = descrip.split("Difficulty:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                realm = descrip.split("Realm:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                dungeon = descrip.split("Dungeon:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                level = descrip.split("Level:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                party = descrip.split("Size:** ")[1].replace("\n", "")

                text = emb.fields[-1].value
                text = text.split("**World")[1]
                text = f"**Group Type:** {grouptype}\n**World" + text
                emb.remove_field(index=0)
                emb.add_field(name="Options", value=text, inline=False)
                if text.count("Not selected") == 0:
                    channel = self.client.get_channel(channelid)
                    if channel is None:
                        await interaction.response.send_message("Channel is not configured.", ephemeral=True)
                        return
                    
                    emb.colour = discord.Colour.green()
                    emb.set_footer(text="LFG Request has been posted")

                    emb1 = discord.Embed(description=f"{'' if desc == 'None' else desc}", colour=discord.Colour.blue(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
                    emb1.set_author(name=f"{interaction.user} is looking for a group", icon_url=userpfp)
                    emb1.set_thumbnail(url=userpfp)
                    emb1.add_field(name="Options", value=f"**Difficulty:** {diff}\n**realm** {realm}\n**Dungeon:** {dungeon}\n**Sigil Level:** {level}", inline=True)
                    emb1.add_field(name="Group Details", value=text, inline=True)
                    emb1.add_field(name=f"Party (1/{party})", value=f"<@{interaction.user.id}>", inline=False)

                    msg = await channel.send(embed=emb1, view=ChoiceView())
                    await msg.create_thread(name=f"{interaction.user} Chat")
                    await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb, view=None)
                    return
                
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb)
                return
            

            elif interaction.data["custom_id"].startswith("worldtype"):
                if interaction.message.interaction.user != interaction.user:
                    await interaction.response.send_message("This LFG request is not yours.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                with open("config.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    config = json.load(f)
                    channelid = config["channel"]
                
                worldtype = interaction.data['values'][0]
                emb = interaction.message.embeds[0]
                descrip = emb.description
                desc = descrip.split("Description:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                diff = descrip.split("Difficulty:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                realm = descrip.split("Realm:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                dungeon = descrip.split("Dungeon:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                level = descrip.split("Level:** ")[1].split("**")[0].replace("\n", "")
                party = descrip.split("Size:** ")[1].replace("\n", "")

                text = emb.fields[-1].value
                text = text.split("**World")[0]
                text = text + f"**World Type:** {worldtype}"
                emb.remove_field(index=0)
                emb.add_field(name="Options", value=text, inline=False)
                if text.count("Not selected") == 0:
                    channel = self.client.get_channel(channelid)
                    if channel is None:
                        await interaction.response.send_message("Channel is not configured.", ephemeral=True)
                        return
                    
                    emb.colour = discord.Colour.green()
                    emb.set_footer(text="LFG Request has been posted")

                    emb1 = discord.Embed(description=f"{'' if desc == 'None' else desc}", colour=discord.Colour.blue(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
                    emb1.set_author(name=f"{interaction.user} is looking for a group", icon_url=userpfp)
                    emb1.set_thumbnail(url=userpfp)
                    emb1.add_field(name="Options", value=f"**Difficulty:** {diff}\n**Realm:** {realm}\n**Dungeon:** {dungeon}\n**Sigil Level:** {level}", inline=True)
                    emb1.add_field(name="Group Details", value=text, inline=True)
                    emb1.add_field(name=f"Party (1/{party})", value=f"<@{interaction.user.id}>", inline=False)

                    msg = await channel.send(embed=emb1, view=ChoiceView())
                    await msg.create_thread(name=f"{interaction.user} Chat")
                    await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb, view=None)
                    return


                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb)
                return


            elif interaction.data["custom_id"].startswith("join"):
                emb = interaction.message.embeds[0]
                limit = int(emb.fields[-1].name.split("/")[1].replace(")", ""))
                members = emb.fields[-1].value
                if str(userid) in members:
                    await interaction.response.send_message("You are already in this group.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                if members.count("<@") >= limit:
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"This group is at its party limit of **{limit}**", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                name = f"Party ({members.count('<@')+1})/{limit}"
                value = f"{members} <@{userid}>"

                thread = None
                for mythread in interaction.channel.threads:
                    if mythread.id == interaction.message.id:
                        thread = mythread

                if thread is None:
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Thread for this group was not found.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                try:
                    await thread.add_user(interaction.user)
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(exc)
                    pass

                emb1 = discord.Embed(description=f"{interaction.user.mention} joined the group", colour=discord.Colour.green())
                emb1.set_author(name=interaction.user, icon_url=userpfp)
                await thread.send(embed=emb1)


                emb.remove_field(index=2)
                emb.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb)
                return  

            elif interaction.data["custom_id"].startswith("leave"):
                emb = interaction.message.embeds[0]
                limit = int(emb.fields[-1].name.split("/")[1].replace(")", ""))
                members = emb.fields[-1].value
                if str(userid) not in members:
                    await interaction.response.send_message("You are not in this group.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
                
                name = f"Party ({members.count('<@')-1}/{limit})"
                value = members.replace(f" <@{userid}>", "").replace(f"<@{userid}>", "")

                thread = None
                for mythread in interaction.channel.threads:
                    if mythread.id == interaction.message.id:
                        thread = mythread

                if thread is None:
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Thread for this group was not found.", ephemeral=True)
                    return
         
                try:
                    await thread.remove_user(interaction.user)
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(exc)
                    pass


                emb1 = discord.Embed(description=f"{interaction.user.mention} left the group", colour=discord.Colour.red())
                emb1.set_author(name=interaction.user, icon_url=userpfp)
                await thread.send(embed=emb1)


                emb.remove_field(index=2)
                emb.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb)

                if value.count("<@") == 0:
                    await interaction.message.delete()
                    await thread.delete()

                return



        except Exception as exc:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            raise(exc)
         


    @app_commands.command(name="lfg", description="Create a looking for group request.")
    async def lfg(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        with open("config.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            config = json.load(f)
            channelid = config["channel"]

        channel = self.client.get_channel(channelid)
        if channel is None:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Channel is not configured.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        if interaction.user.avatar is None:
            userpfp = interaction.user.default_avatar
        else:
            userpfp = interaction.user.avatar
        

        class MessageModal(discord.ui.Modal):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(title="LFM Request", timeout=None, custom_id="createmodal")

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label="Realm",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="Eternal / Seasonal",
                    required=True,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="realm"
                ))

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label="Difficulty",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="Softcore / Hardcore",
                    required=True,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="difficulty"
                ))

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label="Normal or Nightmare Dungeon",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="Leave empty if N/A",
                    required=False,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="dungeon"
                ))

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label="Nightmare Sigil (min level)",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="(1-100) , 0 if N/A",
                    required=False,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="level"
                ))

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label=" Max Party size",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="Party Size",
                    required=True,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="size"
                ))

                self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(
                    label="Group Description",
                    style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                    placeholder="eg. sigil range, no leaches, all welcome",
                    required=False,
                    min_length=1,
                    max_length=250,
                    custom_id="description"
                ))



        await interaction.response.send_modal(MessageModal())
        return

        
        class ChoiceView(discord.ui.View):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(timeout=None)
                self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label=f"Join", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id=f"join", disabled=False))
                self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label=f"Leave", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id=f"leave", disabled=False))
        

        emb = discord.Embed(title="Domain Records", description=f"Click a button to create a new domain record, list your records or delete a record. You can have up to 5 domain records.", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        await interaction.response.send_message("Panel sent.", ephemeral=True)
        msg = await channel.send(embed=emb, view=ChoiceView())
        thread = await msg.create_thread(name=f"{interaction.user} Chat")
        return
        

            
        


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(LFGCommand(client))
```

tryed adding a new option in the from
fixed the code and came back with no errors yet wont respond in discord

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).